# WPF - Selectively binding images to ListView? UI Virtulalizaiton or Async or Any better solution?

Tags: wpf, image, performance, virtualization

Basically,

1. I have images in various directories marked as 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.
   So, The numbers will be showin on the left hand side in UI.
2. Whenever user clicks on a number, the corresponding images from that
   folder should appear in a row\columnlayout(ListView\Listbox) on
   right hand side.

I have done some research and this can be done in multiple ways

1. I can simply bind the images to a listview\listbox. But that will
   make the images load everytime user clicks on number
2. I can assign all the images from all the directories to the
   listview, hide the scrollbar and Scroll to the relevant image. I can
   try to take advantage of UI Virtualization. But, only Stackpanel
   allows virtualization, and I need to use a wrappanel to achieve the
   effect. So, really, I cant use UI virtualization
3. I can load all the images in the memory using Async mechanism,
   there wont be any performance effect but memory footprint will
   increase and I would load all the images even if user never clicks
   on    them.
4. May be I need to use some sort of Data Virtualization?

Whats the best way to go about this? Can anyone help? I have tried to go through as many SO questions as possible, but I couldnt find a satisfactory answer. Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I basically ended up trying all of the options - they all seem to work but ended up using the one that I thought is good enough for my needs

1)

```
public class ImageCache
{
    public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>>> ImageList =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>>>();


    public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> GetValue(string folder)
    {
        ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> c = null;
        c = ImageList.GetOrAdd(folder, c => GetPhotosByCategory(folder)).Value;
        return c;
    }



    private static Lazy<ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>> GetPhotosByCategory(string folder)
    {
        Retrieve images and return the list
    }
}
```

2) The other option I tried was to use AsyncCache - Links are [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=19957) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/194016be-0a88-4d61-9d23-364d359ff055/a-question-about-asynccache?forum=parallelextensions). But decided to just use the first option as mentioned above as it fit my requirements.